# What is the advantage of little endian format?

Tags: architecture, storage, advantages, endianness

Intel processors (and maybe some others) use the little endian format for storage.

I always wonder why someone would want to store the bytes in reverse order. Does this format have any advantages over the big endian format?

Comment: The 6502 was an early (the first?) pipelined processor. I seem to remember some claim about it being little-endian for some performance-related issue due to the pipeline - but I have no idea now what that issue might have been. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Steve314: My answer explains how little endian helps with performance in a pipelined CPU: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/95854/27874

Comment: Little-endian, big-endian - you must choose one or the other.  Like driving on the left or the right side of the road.

Comment: It goes back in the old recesses of my mind, but I seem to remember that the reason was because of patent issues with Motorola. No technical reason at all behind having 2 formats.

Comment: I suggest you to write some code in ASM, preferably for an "old-school" architecture such as 6502 or Z80. You will immediately see why these use little endian. Architectures that use big endian have certain characteristics to their instruction set that make that format preferable instead. It's not an arbitrary decision to make!

Comment: @noah1989 you aren't particular; any reference to "obviousness" in IT shall be really grounded, or they are void. I have been writing much code for PDP-11 and 6502 but I'm still wondering why it would be preferred...

Comment: Each byte-order system has its advantages. Little-endian machines let you read the lowest-byte first, without reading the others. You can check whether a number is odd or even (last bit is 0) very easily, which is cool if you're into that kind of thing. Big-endian systems store data in memory the same way we humans think about data (left-to-right), which makes low-level debugging easier.

Comment: @StefanPaulNoack I've written a fair amount of ARM and x86 assembly...but I have no idea what characteristics you're referring to

Comment: @Assimilater I was specifically refering to 8-bit architectures such as the 6502 or the Z80. For example addition of larger numbers needs to be done in multiple steps using an add-with-carry instruction, which only makes sense when starting at the little end. On larger word-size architectures this does not matter, and big endian can be used, which is more readable when debugging and gives an advantage when handling network protocols, which are big endian as well (but I have not yet bothered to find out why they are).

Comment: @StefanPaulNoack But you can still start at the little end even if the big end is stored first, it's just a decrement operation instead of an increment on the address....

Comment: Also, I don't really see how it relates to higher-order architectures where endianness even comes in to play...8-bit architectures endianness is purely software

Comment: @Assimilater I was trying to say (6 years ago!) that it is not "Like driving on the left or the right side of the road.", but sometimes requires differnet approaches when writing software which are often similar, but not alway entirely symmetric.

Comment: To use the car comparison: when you switch to the other side of the road, things are NOT the a mirror image of the original unless you put the steering wheel on the other side as well.

Comment: Actually it's the Big Endian which has the bytes swapped. Why would you ever want to read 0001 as "a thousand"?.

Comment: @PabloAriel That is an inaccurate analogy. Take "987,654"(common human decimal format) and assuming the thousand separating comma is actually separating words or bytes; the little endian version would be 654,987.

Comment: @MaxPower Not at all. That would be the big endian version! It's just you're not following the right coordinate convention for memory where +X goes left and +Y goes up, which is obviously because the larger a number the more digits you add leftmost. Computers are calculators and you're trying to fit in there your human understanding of text (going right), which has nothing to do in there.

Comment: @PabloAriel We just have a definition/description problem, not a disagreement about the underlying storage. XY coordinates of physical arrays are arbitrary and not really relevant to the core issue(You could just view it from the backside or in a mirror or rotated 90 degrees and it would function the same.) We are just describing an arbitrary length *sequence* of bits and then chopping it into chunks and displaying the chunks flipped arround. (Not backward in memory but backward in representation.) This sequence can be a storage array, a network stream, or other, and come from any angle.

Answer (score 262, accepted):

There are arguments either way, but one point is that in a little-endian system, the address of a given value in memory, taken as a 32, 16, or 8 bit width, is the same.

In other words, if you have in memory a two byte value:

```
0x00f0   16
0x00f1    0
```

taking that '16' as a 16-bit value (c 'short' on most 32-bit systems) or as an 8-bit value (generally c 'char') changes only the fetch instruction you use — not the address you fetch from.

On a big-endian system, with the above layed out as:

```
0x00f0    0
0x00f1   16
```

you would need to increment the pointer and then perform the narrower fetch operation on the new value.

So, in short, ‘on little endian systems, casts are a no-op.’

Comment: Assuming, of course, that the high-order bytes that you didn't read can reasonably be ignored (e.g. you know that they're zero anyway).

Comment: @Steve314: If I'm in C downcasting from 32 to 16 bits (e.g.) on a 2's-complement system - the vast majority of systems - the bytes don't need to be zero to be ignored. Regardless of their value I can ignore them and remain compliant with the C standard and programmer expectations.

Comment: @Joe - that's another example of "can reasonably be ignored". A third would be all-bits-set for signed twos-complement values. But I see your point more clearly now - the implication of "casts are a no-op" makes my "assuming ..." automatically true, and the zeros thing irrelevant.

Comment: This is the best answer, I think. It certainly simplifies the hardware and microcode, especially when you have arbitrary-precision arithmetic. Only humans are inconvenienced when reading dumps, and that's only because some of us read left-to-right. It's similar to stacks, do they grow "up" or "down" :)

Comment: I'm wondering weather this isn't a disadvantage even ... this kind of pointer casting is highly nonportable -- because there are big endian architectures.

Comment: @Stritzinger -- we're talking about the assembly/machine code generated by a compiler, which can't be portable. The higher level language code to compile is portable -- it just compiles to different operations on the different architectures (as all ops do).

Comment: I don't buy this argument, because on big-endian architectures, a pointer could point to the end, rather than the beginning, of a whatever it is that you are referring to and than you'd have exactly the same advantage.

Comment: @dan_waterworth not quite -- keep in mind the pointer arithmetic rules in C, for instance, and what happens when you increment or decrement casts of the same pointer.  You can move the complexity, but you can't eliminate it.

Comment: @jimwise, This problem only occurs because of the C standard though. The architecture would be just as efficient if there were some C variation in which pointers point to the end of whatever you are referring to. My instinct is that it would also be possible to write code which is in conformance with C and that a compiler would be able to translate the pointers to end-pointing pointers during some whole-program optimization, the obvious problem being with shared libraries.

Comment: Sure -- if you redesign C so that it's natural convention aligns with a little-endian system, it would be the big-endian system which needed added instructions.  But then what?  Would struct and union pointers also point to the last address of the corresponding structure?  Would this be a better language?  :-)

Comment: "So, in short, ‘on little endian systems, casts are a no-op.’" That may be true, but if you are working with byte strings and low-level algorithms (common in crypto), converting to words and arrays on little endian machines is a royal pain, and your solution will vary depending on if it is a 64-, 32- or 16-bit processor. And there is a time penalty. On big endian machines this is a no brainer.

Comment: I'm not sure i follow -- could you give me an example of this difference?  On either arch, you need to know the size of an array member to find any but the first member of the array, right?

Comment: Not having no-op for casting an integer or pointer to smaller size is an advantage in sense one shall explicitly realize he could lost potentially important data bits. This is the more important the farther a program is from sandbox level:)

Comment: I've been staring at this for the better part of an hour to try and grasp why it would be beneficial. In my naive world casts are always a no-op regardless. It just makes more sense to assume your interpretation of the following bytes changes, not the position, when you perform a cast. I work with byte arrays all the time that have mixed values of 16-bit and 32-bit integers and not being able to type cast as a struct is truly infuriating...and the cost of building an integer using shift operations isn't free...

Comment: I guess that also comes down to convention...networking protocols I've worked with most are usually big endian...I haven't really touched USB but I hear it's little endian...but still that sounds like a recipe for disaster when mixing integers of varying lengths...

Comment: Oh I see, this is for integer value casts.... `short x = 16; char y = (char)x;`

Comment: Downcasting is an extremely niche advantage for an operation that makes a very small proportion of real code. There is no way chip designers would make such a major architectural choice based on that. And who is to say you want your downcast to discard the high-order bytes rather than the low-order bytes?

Answer (score 77):

OK, here's the reason as I've had it explained to me: **Addition and subtraction**

When you add or subtract multi-byte numbers, you have to start with the least significant byte. If you're adding two 16-bit numbers for example, there may be a carry from the least significant byte to the most significant byte, so you have to start with the least significant byte to see if there is a carry. This is the same reason that you start with the rightmost digit when doing longhand addition. You can't start from the left.

Consider an 8-bit system that fetches bytes sequentially from memory. If it fetches the least significant byte *first*, it can start doing the addition *while* the most significant byte is being fetched from memory. This parallelism is why performance is better in little endian on such as system. If it had to wait until both bytes were fetched from memory, or fetch them in the reverse order, it would take longer.

This is on old 8-bit systems. On a modern CPU I doubt the byte order makes any difference and we use little endian only for historical reasons.

Comment: Ah - so it's roughly the same reason I use little-endian chunk ordering for big integers. I should have worked that out. People really need to get working on cybernetics *now* - my brain's already in desperate need of some replacement parts and some radical upgrades, I can't wait forever!

Comment: A thought - the 6502 didn't do much 16-bit math in hardware - it was, after all, an 8 bit processor. But it *did* do relative addressing, using 8-bit signed offsets relative to a 16-bit base address.

Comment: Note that this idea still matters for multiple precision integer arithmetic (as said by Steve314), but at the word level. Now, most operations are not directly affected by the endianness of the processor: one can still store the least significant word first on a big-endian system, as done by GMP. Little-endian processors still have an advantage for the few operations (e.g. some string conversions?) that could be easier done by reading one byte at a time, since only on a little-endian system, the byte ordering of such numbers is correct.

Comment: little-endian processors have an advantage in case the memory bandwidth is limited, like in some 32-bit ARM processors with 16-bit memory bus, or the 8088 with 8-bit data bus: the processor can just load the low half and do add/sub/mul... with it while waiting for the higher half

Comment: Well, you could just read the value from the highest address to the lowest.

Comment: ^exactly. This isn't the reason. It's the casting reason

Comment: Fantastic answer.

Answer (score 57):

> I always wonder why someone would want to store the bytes in reverse order.

Big-endian and little-endian are only "normal order" and "reverse order" from a human perspective, and then only if all of these are true...

1. You're reading the values on the screen or on paper.
2. You put the lower memory addresses on the left, and the higher ones on the right.
3. You're writing in hex, with the high-order nybble on the left, or binary, with the most significant bit on the left.
4. You read left-to-right.

Those are all human conventions that don't matter at all to a CPU. If you were to retain #1 and #2, and flip #3, little-endian would seem "perfectly natural" to people who read Arabic or Hebrew, which are written right-to-left.

And there are other human conventions that make big-endian that seem unnatural, like...

- The "higher" (most significant) byte should be at the "higher" memory address.

Back when I was mostly programming 68K and PowerPC, I considered big-endian to be "right" and little-endian to be "wrong". But since I've been doing more ARM and Intel work, I've gotten used to little-endian. It really doesn't matter.

Comment: Numbers are in fact written from [most significant digit] left to [least significant digit] right in Arabic and Hebrew.

Comment: Then why are bits within a byte stored in "big endian" format? Why not be consistent?

Comment: They aren't - bit 0 is by convention the least significant, and bit 7 the most significant.  Moreover, you can't generally put an order on bits within a byte, since bits aren't individually addressable.  Of course, they might have a physical order in a given communication protocol or storage media, but unless you're working at the low-level protocol or hardware level, you don't need to concern yourself with this order.

Comment: @Stewart: Yes they are - bit 0 is by convention the right-most bit, with bit-7 on the left.  Also, all C-programmers should concern themselves with this ordering; if they don't, it's very easy to write code that is not portable across platforms *(the original version of `sed` - which we had to fix for an "Advanced C in Unix" class - was badly broken on all platforms that weren't 32-bit little-endian)*

Comment: BlueRaja: only by convention of writing on paper. This has nothing in common with CPU architecture. You can write the byte as 0-7 LSB-MSB instead of 7-0 MSB-LSB and nothing changes from algorithm point of view.

Comment: 5. Program Counter, Stack Pointer and the likes are incremented instead of decremented. While I don't know of architectures with PC growing down (which still would be an arbitrary choice), SP growing down is quite common. So while "write short, read char" works as cast on low-endian, if you push short, pop char, you're in for a surprise.

Comment: @SF.: "Push short, pop *anything but short*" will get you a surprise anyway.  Even if you're not corrupting the stack by pushing bytes you never pop or vice versa...x86 (32-bit), for example, really *really* wants the stack to be dword-aligned, and pushing or popping anything that causes the stack pointer to not be a multiple of 4 can cause alignment issues.  And even if it didn't, stuff's pushed a whole word/dword/qword/etc at a time -- so the low byte will still be the first one you get when you pop.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: Bits are not stored in big- or little-Endian format.  The computing industry has MORE OR LESS settled on right-to-left bit numbering, where bit 0 is the least significant bit (LSB) and bit n-1 (in an n-bit object) is the most significant bit (MSB).  IT WAS NOT ALWAYS THUS.  The Data General Nova series numbered bits from the left: bit 0 was the MSB, bit 15 the LSB.  MIL-STD-1553B and F-16 ICD sheets (pretty much a de facto standard in defense) still number bits that way.

Comment: @SF: On the Tracor SuperSIMP (a proprietary processor used by Tracor for teleprinters and Omega radionavigation systems in the late 1970s and into the 1980s), the Program Counter ran backwards.  (It was a quirk of the way branch addresses for jump tables were calculated.  If you viewed the PC as running forward, branch table offset calculations were "interesting".)  During a certain period, a lot of the programmers in Austin spent some time hacking SuperSIMP code.  You got used to it.

Comment: @Stewart: ANSI/MIL-STD-1815A, for the Ada programming language, called out a facility for numbering bits, but left the ordering convention up to the implementor.  This had the highly undesirable side-effect of rendering code non-portable, if one Ada compiler numbered from the left, and the other numbered from the right.  The rationale was that there was AT THAT TIME no industry consensus on bit numbering, and Ada was going to be used on processors that did it both ways.

Comment: "little-endian would seem "perfectly natural" to people who read Arabic or Hebrew, which are written right-to-left" actually, that's not true. In Arabic and Hebrew you read the entire sentence from right-to-left. Reading little-endian on paper as you describe does result in you reading the words from right-to-left, but the words would still be ordered on paper from left-to-right.

Comment: The comment "They aren't - bit 0 is by convention the least significant" is not in the spirit of what @tskuzzy was asking.  Ok 0 is at least defined as the least significant bit in a byte but then it's not displayed left to right like the bytes (where byte 0 contains the least significant byte as *is* displayed on the left).

Comment: Best to define in terms of a chronological stream of bits rather than left or right which could just be stage left or audience left regarding the machine storage&processing. In all of mathematics in all the world regardless of the numeral base the convention for display is the least sig digit is on the right and most sig on the left. Some operations work well chronologically from least sig to most sig(addition) and others that work well from most to least sig(reading and rounding), whether done by machine or human. If anything should swap it is the mem address display so bigger is on the left.

Answer (score 20):

With 8 bit processors it was certainly more efficienct, you could perform an 8 or 16bit operation without needing different code and without needing to buffer extra values.

It's still better for some addition operations if you are dealing a byte at a time.

But there is no reason that big-endian is more natural - in English you use thirteen (little endian) and twenty three (big endian)

Comment: Big-endian is indeed easier for humans because it does not require rearranging the bytes. For example, on a PC, `0x12345678` is stored as `78 56 34 12` whereas on a BE system it’s `12 34 56 78` (byte 0 is on the left, byte 3 is on the right). Note how the larger the number is (in terms of bits), the more swapping it requires; a WORD would require one swap; a DWORD, two passes (three total swaps); a QWORD three passes (7 total), and so on. That is, `(bits/8)-1` swaps. Another option is reading them both forwards **and** backwards (reading each byte forwards, but scanning the whole # backwards).

Comment: One-hundred-and-thirteen is either middle-endian, or else big-endian with "thirteen" being essentially one non-decimal digit. When we spell out numbers, there are some minor deviations from the constant-base conventions that we use for digits, but once you strip out those special cases the rest is big-endian - millions before thousands, thousands before hundreds etc.

Comment: @Synetech- fortunately the computer doesn't have to care how humans read them. That's like claiming that NAND flash is better because ot'

Comment: @Steve314, the spelled-out words of numbers don’t matter, it’s the numerical readout that is what we use when we program.

Martin, no computers don’t have to care how humans read numbers, but if it’s easy for humans to read them, then programming (or other related work) becomes easier and some flaws and bugs can be reduced or avoided.

Comment: @steve314 And in Danish, "95" is pronounced "fem halvfems" (five, plus four-and-a-half twenties).

Comment: @Synetech: `0x12345678` is stored as `87 65 43 21`, depending on how one *chooses* to write it. How one writes something rather arbitrary (read as: context dependent).

Answer (score 16):

Nobody else has answered WHY this might be done, lots of stuff about consequences.

Consider an 8 bit processor which can load a single byte from memory in a given clock cycle.

Now, if you want to load a 16 bit value, into (say) the one and only 16 bit register you have - ie the program counter, then a simple way to do it is:

- Load a byte from the fetch location
- shift that byte to the left 8 places
- increment memory fetch location by 1
- load the next byte (into the low order part of the register)

the outcome: you only ever increment the fetch location, you only ever load into the low order part of you wider register, and you only need to be able to shift left. (Of course, shifting right is helpful for other operations so this one is a bit of a side show.)

A consequence of this is that the 16 bit (double byte) stuff is stored in order Most..Least. I.e., the smaller address has the most significant byte - so big endian.

If you instead tried to load using little endian, you would need to load a byte into the lower part of your wide register, then load the next byte into a staging area, shift it, and then pop it into the top of your wider register. Or use a more complex arrangement of gating to be able to selectively load into the top or bottom byte.

The result of trying to go little endian is you either need more silicon (switches and gates), or more operations.

In other words, in terms of getting bang for buck back in the old days, you got more bang for most performance and smallest silicon area.

These days, these considerations and pretty much irrelevant, but things like pipeline fill *may* still be a bit of a big deal.

When it comes to writing s/w, life is frequently easier when using little endian addressing.

(And the big endian processors tend to be big endian in terms of byte ordering and little endian in terms of bits-in-bytes. But some processors are strange and will use big endian bit ordering as well as byte ordering. This makes life *very* interesting for the h/w designer adding memory-mapped peripherals but is of no other consequence to the programmer.)

Answer (score 13):

The Japanese date convention is "big endian" - yyyy/mm/dd. This is handy for sorting algorithms, which can use a simple string-compare with the usual first-character-is-most-significant rule.

Something similar applies for big-endian numbers stored in a most-significant-field-first record. The significance order of the bytes within the fields matches the significance of the fields within the record, so you can use a `memcmp` to compare records, not caring much whether you're comparing two longwords, four words, or eight separate bytes.

Flip the order of significance of the fields and you get the same advantage, but for little-endian numbers rather than big-endian.

This has very little practical significance, of course. Whether your platform is big-endian or little-endian, you can order a records fields to exploit this trick if you really need to. It's just a pain if you need to write *portable* code.

I may as well include a link to the classic appeal...

http://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?url=ftp://ftp.rfc-editor.org/in-notes/ien/ien137.txt

**EDIT**

An extra thought. I once wrote a big integer library (to see if I could), and for that, the 32-bit-wide chunks are stored in little-endian order, irrespective of how the platform orders the bits in those chunks. The reasons were...

1. A lot of algorithms just naturally start working at the least significant end, and want those ends to be matched. For example in addition, the carries propogate to more and more significant digits, so it makes sense to start at the least significant end.
2. Growing or shrinking a value just means adding/removing chunks at the end - no need to shift chunks up/down. Copying may still be needed due to memory reallocation, but not often.

This has no obvious relevance to processors, of course - until CPUs are made with hardware big-integer support, it's purely a library thing.

Comment: That's not just the Japanese data convention, that's the ISO 8601 date convention.

Answer (score 3):

jimwise made a good point. There is another issue, in little endian you can do the following:

```
byte data[4];
int num=0;
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    num += data[i]<<i*8; 

OR 

num = *(int*)&data; //is interpreted as

mov dword data, num ;or something similar it has been some time
```

More straight forward for programmers which are not affected by the obvious disadvantage of swapped locations in the memory. I personally find big endian to be inverse of what is natural :). 12 should be stored and written as 21 :)

Comment: This just proves that it's faster/easier to work in whatever format that is native to the CPU. It doesn't say anything about whether it's better. The same thing goes for big endian: `for(i=0; i<4; i++) { num += data[i] << (24 - i * 8); }` corresponds to `move.l data, num` on a big endian CPU.

Comment: @martin: one less subtraction is better in my book

Comment: It doesn't really matter as the compiler will unroll the loop anyway. In any case, many CPUs have byte swapping instructions to handle this problem.

Comment: i dont agree bcoz on big endian, i would do { num <<= 8; num |= data[i]; } at least this does not have to calculate left shift count using mul

Comment: @ali: your code will do the exact operation I wrote and will not work on big endian.

Comment: @cem: you can test and see with your own eyes if you don't believe me http://pastebin.com/NQ6GzR4b

Comment: @ali: ok you are right, my bad, sometimes << operator can deceive.

Answer (score 3):

1. The main reason is that a cast operation itself becomes invisible to hardware; recasting a pointer does not require an arithmetic operation to change the address of a pointer and does not rely on the compiler knowing the previous type to know how much to offset the pointer by. To overcome this, the pointer could always point to the end of the data in memory but this is more unintuitive than using little endian to solve the the problem
2. Let's say someone stored a dword 00 00 00 01 in big endian format at 0x100. You'd need to know the format of the data at the address to be able to read the value you want. With little endian you'd just be able to read a byte from 0x100 and it would be 1, with big endian, you need to know that a dword was stored there and read from 0x103. This abstracts the details of the memory layout less than little endian does because the programmer needs to be aware of the representation of the data.
3. At the hardware level, it may simplify store to load forwarding, because if you write a dword to 0x100 and then read a byte, it would be reading the same address on little endian rather than 0x103. This means store to load forwarding in the store buffer for a byte would require 0 checks. When you load a byte at 0x103, you'd have to check other addresses in the store buffer and their data lengths.

The answers talking about being able to immediately perform an arithmetic operation on the lowest byte while fetching the highest byte is wrong because on big endian, it could just fetch the highest byte first.

Answer (score 2):

> I always wonder why someone would want to store the bytes in reverse order

Decimal number are written big endian. It also how you write it in English  You start with the most significant digit and the next most significant to the least most significant. e.g.

```
1234
```

is one thousand, two hundred and thirty four.

This is way big endian is sometimes called the natural order.

In little endian, this number would be one, twenty, three hundred and four thousand.

However, when you perform arithmetic like addition or subtraction, you start with the end.

```
  1234
+ 0567
  ====
```

You start with 4 and 7, write the lowest digit and remember the carry. Then you add 3 and 6 etc.  For add, subtract or comparison, it is simpler to implement, if you already have logic to read the memory in order, if the numbers are reversed.

To support big endian this way, you need logic to read memory in reverse, or you have RISC process which only operates on registers. ;)

A lot of the Intel x86/Amd x64 design is historical.

Answer (score 1):

Big-endian is useful for some operations (comparisons of "bignums" of equal octet-length springs to mind). Little-endian for others (adding two "bignums", possibly). In the end, it depends on what the CPU hardware has been set up for, it's usually one or the other (some MIPS chips were, IIRC, switchable on boot to be LE or BE).

Answer (score 1):

When only storage and transfer with variable lengths are involved, but no arithmetics with multiple values, then LE is usually easier to write, while BE is easier to read.

Let's take an int-to-string conversion (and back) as a specific example.

```
int val_int = 841;
char val_str[] = "841";
```

When the int is converted to the string, then the least significant digit is easier to extract than the most significant digit. It can all be done in a simple loop with a simple end condition.

```
val_int = 841;
// Make sure that val_str is large enough.

i = 0;
do // Write at least one digit to care for val_int == 0
{
    // Constants, can be optimized by compiler.
    val_str[i] = '0' + val_int % 10;
    val_int /= 10;
    i++;
}
while (val_int != 0);

val_str[i] = '\0';
// val_str is now in LE "148"
// i is the length of the result without termination, can be used to reverse it
```

Now try the same in BE order. Usually you need another divisor that holds the largest power of 10 for the specific number (here 100). You first need to find this, of course. Much more stuff to do.

The string to int conversion is easier to do in BE, when it is done as the reverse write operation. Write stores the most significant digit last, so it should be read first.

```
val_int = 0;
length = strlen(val_str);

for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    // Again a simple constant that can be optimized.
    val_int = 10*val_int + (val_str[i] - '0');
}
```

Now do the same in LE order. Again, you'd need an additional factor starting with 1 and being multiplied by 10 for each digit.

Thus I usually prefer to use BE for storage, because a value is written exactly once, but read at least once and maybe many times. For its simpler structure, I usually also go the route to convert to LE and then reverse the result, even if it writes the value a second time.

Another example for BE storage would be UTF-8 encoding, and many more.